# How to post JSON data from NodeJS to Django?

Tags: node.js, django, post

The architecture of our app uses NodeJS and Django together.

I need to post a JSON data from NodeJS to Django without receiving any request before that from Django. Because, there is a function in NodeJS that generates and returns JSON data such that whenever this data returned, NodeJS must post it to Django.

I don't know any thing about that and have not any idea for that.

What should I do? What APIs/modules do I need to use and how should I work with NodeJS and Django to fulfill it?

Comment: use axios to comunicate between servers through an api gateway.

Answer (score 0):

api can be created in django with necessary permissions & authentication, then can continue with function call in nodejs (any medium to trigger code to submit data in django api).